# How to get an specific kernel version to the extraversion digit from git

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I have some patches for a specific platform which should apply to kernel version **2.6.32.3**. Now that I'm working with git, I already have a clone of the official kernel tree and I'd like to have a private branch for maintaining this patches. When I ask for a list of tags with `git tag -l` I get this for the **2.6.32** series:

```
v2.6.32
v2.6.32-rc1
v2.6.32-rc2
v2.6.32-rc3
v2.6.32-rc4
v2.6.32-rc5
v2.6.32-rc6
v2.6.32-rc7
v2.6.32-rc8
```

On [kernel.org's HTTP repository](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/) one can get all the specific full source and patch tarballs to the extraversion digit (in my case, the **.3** in the end), so how are we supposed to get the same directly through git? Why the tags listed only show "-rcX" for extraversion?

I've searched the web and found people with [this same trouble](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-use-git-to-get-kernel-2-6-38-8-a-943765), but they also ended up unanswered.

Comment: What is `-l` for in `git tag -l`?

Comment: `git tag -l` is used to list the tags on that repository. See `git tag --help` for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have a clone of Linus's repo.

Try the linux-stable repo: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/tags/v2.6.32.3

The http-git-urls don't work, but the git-url should:

`git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`

Comment: Thanks @Christoffer Hammarström, you were right on the spot! I had cloned linus tree from *git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git*. I'm setting the URL to the one you pointed...

Comment: Yes, I'm just waiting for git to finish downloading to check out the desired tags are there :) hang on! hehe..

Comment: Ok! I changed the origin with git remote `git set-url origin git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git` and after `git pull` I got the additional stable tags, including the needed v2.6.32.3. Thanks!